# How would this C struct be translated into Ada

Tags: c, ada

I'm pretty new to Ada and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to use the structs. What would the C structs below look like when they are converted into Ada?

These are the structs I have:

```
struct dataT
{
    int m;
};

struct stack
{
    int top;
    struct dataT items[STACKSIZE];
} st;
```

How would this statement be represented in Ada?

```
st.items[st.top].m
```

Comment: Are you just porting code, or do you need to interface between ada and c using this struct?

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29340438/40851) is a precise equivalent of your C code, but (assuming you’re not interfacing to existing C code) there are things you can do in Ada that make life easier later.

You might want to create stacks of different sizes; having their size determined by a (global?) macro `STACKSIZE` prevents this. To do that, you can use a *discriminated type* (see [ARM 3.7](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-7.html); examples at the end of the chapter, as usual in the Ada Reference Manual):

```
type Stack (Size : Natural) is record
```

It would be good if `Top` was initialized to indicate that the stack is empty:

```
   Top : Natural := 0;
```

It would be great, but not Ada, to be able to then declare the array directly,

```
   Items : array (1 .. Size) of Data_T;
```

but the compiler says `anonymous arrays not allowed as components`. Instead, you have to declare an auxiliary type for the array, which is [unconstrained](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6.html#p3):

```
type Data_T_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Data_T;
```

Then you can declare

```
   Items : Data_T_Array (1 .. Size);
```

(note, use `1 .. Size` so as to have exactly `Size` elements, versus the C declaration which uses zero-based indexing).

Putting it together, you have

```
type Stack (Size : Natural) is record
   Top   : Natural := 0;
   Items : Data_T_Array (1 .. Size);
end record;
```

and you create an instance by specifying the size you want:

```
St : Stack (42);
```

or, more explicitly, by

```
St : Stack (Size => 42);
```

A fine point is that you can declare a stack with a size of zero. You might think that its `Items` would be illegal (effectively, it would have indices `1 .. 0`, and `0` isn’t a legal value of `Positive`); however, this is a valid method of declaring a zero-length array.

Usage would be, for example,

```
St.Top := St.Top + 1;
St.Items (St.Top).M := 1066;
```

Answer (score 5):

Structs are equivalent to records, so your code would look like...

```
type dataT_type is
    record
        m : integer; -- or Interfaces.C.Int, depending on what you are doing
    end record;

dataT : dataT_type;

type dataT_Array is array(1..STACKSIZE) of dataT_type;

type st_type is
    record
        top : integer;
        items : dataT_Array;
    end record;

st : st_type;
```

Accessing the variable would look identical, except for the use of round brackets.

```
st.items(st.top).m
```